# test class type without specifying template argument in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, concept

I would like to select instance by type while iterating via std::apply in a std::tuple.
Since I have multiple times the same class in my tuple I can not just use std::get

Is there a way to express that I want all the variant of A  instead of writting
 `A< ... >`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    public:
        T val;
        
        A(T t) : val(t)
        {};
};

using MyType = std::tuple< A<double> , A<double> , A<int>, bool>;

template<typename T>
void logic(T& c)
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_same<T, A< ... > >::value) 
        std::cout << c.val << std::endl;
}

void printOnlyA(MyType& v)
{
    std::apply([&](auto &&...c) { ( logic(c), ...); }, v);
}

int main() {
    
    A<double> a{3.5};
    A<double> b{5.5};
    A<int> c{2};
    

    MyType dd{std::make_tuple(a,b,c , false)};
    printOnlyA(dd);
    
        
    return 0;
}
```

I m using c++ 20, and would like to avoid the old c++11 approach to std::false_type and std::true_type. I can not figure out the way to do it with concept

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial template specialization. Since partial specialization for functions is not a part of the language a dedicated class template is required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    public:
        T val;
        
        A(T t) : val(t)
        {};
};

using MyType = std::tuple< A<double> , A<double> , A<int>, bool>;

template<typename T>
struct logic_impl
{
    static void exec([[maybe_unused]] T & c)
    {
        // nothing
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct logic_impl<A<T>>
{
    static void exec(A<T> & c)
    {
        std::cout << c.val << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void logic(T& c)
{
    logic_impl<T>::exec(c);
}

void printOnlyA(MyType& v)
{
    std::apply([&](auto &&... c) { (logic(c), ...); }, v);
}

int main() {
    
    A<double> a{3.5};
    A<double> b{5.5};
    A<int> c{2};
    

    MyType dd{std::make_tuple(a,b,c , false)};
    printOnlyA(dd);
    
        
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBLSAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8VK2mPYFDEIETMQEmT5%2BAOyV1el1DQRFkTFxCbb1jc3Z7QojvWH9pYNSAJS2qF7EyOwc5v5hyN5YANQm/m5Ok8SYrEfYJhoAgls7e5iHxwReifRXN/d3BJgsHyYfxebgIAE9EoxWM8ACpfO5nLwOfY/e6tKx3fZY/aJLzRWh4ZAgb7Y0n7GH7ABuYiOGNuZOxJIZKIgFIIC32ICpYgg7KZDJM6MFABFad8RWK7t8vKkjPsALJgmEQ55HYX7SboEAgN4fTBHNwog3oFb4/X%2BbD7UhG44mvGfC1Wm0nQRXa3RVCeL7%2BOnfP4Agx/A3gyHMNjk%2BG3RHI2ioYCEgD6eAD4qFmOxkyBhKpqDw6H2mFUmGQEBMAFYrBWWEwwbEE14GDLMOhy6Ky%2BqKeYAGz7ZALfmHNP05kAehH%2BwYqAICDCwAHEqlrVFPvFv3%2BgKDrxVYdhkejBH2sfjyCTKeO92OcItkcFdNJmccyBzeYLRZLF7cV8t3d7/fTWNvAd7wILUUBWA8DQNXsADpqVoEEoM1bVXFoSVhwApdU2XX01wDIFzVBbdoQja87kpXN8yPQlWR/PtUzvbEqJPZMPgNL9kLfCA6JXRdRSlMiKJxYgwgIAB5BhaDBW4IEVZVIR/Sk/zRBisSQkAmESD4wVLCtu1bCAmC8IhDjMLtu2gizf0HCx9ggJiuKWfYLOg/sfUHYVrUUtCF1RET9mrMIIA5QD/0OUKPztM0rn2Jhb38aCywlHj0OdSKHUtaJbzLBKkpU50ROi0x0TMXL534lLZJVfZ0BbdE1OrABrTAE11egDNIaJSCfa0qDEJR%2B0w5LSUSYTBHEyTpJq1y8qAxlQvON5iAYfYNG8zC7g4JZaE4MteD8DgtFIVBODcaxrA1FY1lVMx/B4UgCE0TalgakAyw0fROEkPbHqOzheAUEB3oeg7NtIOBYBgRAwIBOg4nISg0Bh%2Bh4mALguDMPg6D%2BYgAYgaIfuiMIGjBTg7sRtgxokkmQdILBqyMcQafwc4HDwSlMABmnC2LIyNjukSqh%2BglomIYmPCwH6CGElhSdBqgDGABQADU8EwAB3UTQ1lmRBBEMR2AqfhBEUFR1Bp3QuH0QxjDOyx9DwaIAcgJZUESGpOYAWg9zU1VMSxrDMDR9g9gB1MR4NDwspaYYOQ8hdBDEff6qmLGoXAYdxPBaPQQhmEoyj0PI0gEMY/Etouaj6fP5g6VOuimUu9DsOuBG6Roq4Gcphh6RvLczdu887iQlgUS71j0KXMD50Hto4XbSH2w7jo4VQAA4uw9rtJH2YBkCfNHoLMWzTv9u39lwQgSBM27rQ8JG4mvrgFl4YGtAWZ7Xve2evtIGW3oXn6y9/qA3uo9JY4MobgVxAQeGXFUD3y7s2S%2BXcjbCFEOIQ2sgTZqElucaepA1ai0SLLLaO1vo02XqJIy0D9ioCoPsNeG8t47z3vsA%2BR8IB30SLDYgj9n6gJBu/UgCALhYHiEFD6HAf5/3eovXgQDbAgNfk9UgL1/6z38OQpef0BFv1IRwMwWj5E6OUUI9mON0ggEkEAA%3D)